# Google sheets duration to seconds

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell formatted as a duration (6:49:00)
I want to convert that to an Integer of total seconds
This formula gives me the right number of seconds =C3*60
409:00:00 <-- But I want this as just 409

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To convert duration to an integer expressing the number of seconds, use a formula such as

```
=value(A1*24*3600)
```

Time values are recorded so that 1 is one day. Multiplying by 24 (hours/day) and 3600 (seconds/hour) converts that to seconds. Then `value` makes it a number rather than duration.

---

Old answer, about formatting only.

You don't need any formulas to format duration as the number of seconds.

1. Go to Format > Number > More formats > More data and time formats
2. Delete the pre-filled format fields and add "Elapsed seconds" from the dropdown menu.

Comment: I want the seconds in a different column that the time duration as an integer   
So I can then use that for another formula

Comment: Edited the answer. By the way, 6:49:00 is not 409 seconds.

Comment: seems not to work with google sheets

Answer (score 23):

I have found this solution:

let the cell A1 filled with duration like `1:22:33`, than formula

```
=HOUR(A1)*3600+MINUTE(A1)*60+SECOND(A1)
```

will do the trick.

For example, `1:01:01` -> `3661`

Comment: This requires the `A1` cell to be formatted in exactly HH:MM:SS form. No missing hour. No decimal after the seconds.

Comment: Not working when hours > 24

Answer (score 7):

`=HOUR(A1)` will NOT work if your hours in the duration is `> 24` of course. So the last example is not correct.

What will work is the following.

Given: A duration in hours and minutes. eg `225:04` or `9:20` or `62:35`
Format must be set as this (Elapsed hours:minutes)

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1, ":"), 0, 1)*60 + INDEX(SPLIT(A1, ":"), 0, 2)
```

Comment: Well Done! !!

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but maybe helps someone:

1. Multiply any duration (HH:MM:SS) by 86400 (number of
   seconds in a day)
2. Format as a number: Format > Number > Number

   =C3*86400